# Change of cj.bst sytle bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I recently began to use Latex and bibtex.

I would like to know, What I need doing to edit the `cj.bst` style (is the most closest style that I found to write my undergraduate career final project).

I need to change several things on it.

1.) I need that all authors (books, journals, inbook, proceedings, etc) have been separated by `,` and not an `and` when bibtex write the last author.

For example:

(before)

> Sorenson, J., Hura, G., Glaeser, R., and Gordon, H. (2000) “What can x-ray scattering tell us about the radial distribution functions of water?”. J. Chem. Phys., 113, 9149–9161.

(later)

> Sorenson, J., Hura, G., Glaeser, R., Gordon, H. (2000) “What can x-ray scattering tell us about the radial distribution functions of water?”. J. Chem. Phys., 113, 9149–9161.

1.1) When a book have two or more authors, I need to separate authors by `;` and that @book, @inbook or @incollection tittles doesn't appear emphasized .

For example:

(before)

> Robinson, G. W., Zhu, S.-B., and Evans, M. (1996) *Water in Biology,Chemistry and Physics. Experimental Overviews and Computational Methodologies*. World Scientific.

(later)

> Robinson, G. W.; Zhu, S.-B.; Evans, M. 1996 Water in Biology,Chemistry and Physics. Experimental Overviews and Computational Methodologies. World Scientific.

2) The last that I need is that years of publications (books, journals, inbook, proceedings, etc) doesn't appear whit parenthesis.

For example:

(before)

> Franks, F. (2000) Water: A Matrix of Life. Royal Society of Chemistry.

(later)

> Franks, F., 2000. Water: A Matrix of Life. Royal Society of Chemistry.

I hope that your can help me.
PD: Sorry if my English is not well writed.

Answer (score 4):

The [cj.bst](http://mirror.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/misc/cj.bst) bibliography style file is quite old and, more importantly, appears to have been hacked in some unusual ways. For instance, it appears to be based on an older file which was meant for numerical-style citations, but it looks like it has been modified extensively so that it now produces author-year citations (instead of numerical-style citations). Any further hacking of the file is quite likely to create havoc, I'm afraid.

I recommend that you run the `makebst` utility -- at a command prompt, type "latex makebst" to start the program -- and follow the detailed prompts to create a brand-new `.bst` file that will be tailored to your precise formatting needs. What this utility will *not* do for you, though, is provide an option for separating authors' names with semicolons for entries of type `@book`.